# bootstrap radio button in JOOMLA in not working fine?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, joomla, joomla-extensions

following is my bootstrap radio button that i am trying to use in my JOOMLA extension.

```
<fieldset id="myEdit" class="radio btn-group">
                  <input type="radio" id="myEdit0" value="0">
                  <label for="myEdit0" class="btn active btn-danger">Yes</label>
                  <input type="radio" id="myEdit1" value="1">
                  <label for="myEdit1" class="btn">No</label>
 </fieldset>
```

[image]

this button works fine when i click on YES but when i click back on NO it became totally unresponsive. other way around my radio button only works one time. . .but as i copied this html from
JOOMLA global configuration window, its working fine there.

Anticipating helpful response

Comment: What Joomla version installed on your site?

Comment: Radio buttons in HTML are very unintuitive. If you have just one button in the set, that button cannot be unselected once selected. It's somewhat like the problem in checkboxes where you can't post an empty set of selections that replaces previously selected values. What field in global configuration are you looking at? Are you sure that it does not have multiple button options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok i found following piece of js code in template.js of JOOMLA administrator side. and by changing html as follow it worked

```
<fieldset id="myEdit" class="radio btn-group">
                                        <input type="radio" id="myEdit0" value="1" name="myEdit">
                                        <label for="myEdit0" class="btn">Yes</label>
                                        <input type="radio" id="myEdit1" value="0" name="myEdit">
                                        <label for="myEdit1" class="btn btn-danger">No</label>
</fieldset>
```

template.js

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('*[rel=tooltip]').tooltip()

    // Turn radios into btn-group
    $('.radio.btn-group label').addClass('btn');
    $(".btn-group label:not(.active)").click(function()
    {
        var label = $(this);
        var input = $('#' + label.attr('for'));

        if (!input.prop('checked')) {
            label.closest('.btn-group').find("label").removeClass('active btn-success btn-danger btn-primary');
            if (input.val() == '') {
                label.addClass('active btn-primary');
            } else if (input.val() == 0) {
                label.addClass('active btn-danger');
            } else {
                label.addClass('active btn-success');
            }
            input.prop('checked', true);
        }
    });
    $(".btn-group input[checked=checked]").each(function()
    {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            $("label[for=" + $(this).attr('id') + "]").addClass('active btn-primary');
        } else if ($(this).val() == 0) {
            $("label[for=" + $(this).attr('id') + "]").addClass('active btn-danger');
        } else {
            $("label[for=" + $(this).attr('id') + "]").addClass('active btn-success');
        }
    });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

It´s difficult do find decent documentation on that, and a similar result that seems to be more bootstrap 3 compatible is here. This is working in joomla 3.5 front end.

```
    <fieldset class="radio btn-group">
        <label class="btn btn-default btn-danger" for="feedback0" >
        <input type="radio" id="feedback0" value="0" name="feedback" checked="checked">No</label>
        <label class="btn btn-default" for="feedback1">
        <input type="radio" id="feedback1" value="1" name="feedback">Yes</label>
    </fieldset>
```